# How to display tiff file in color?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have several tiff files (32 bit) from my experiment which I would like to view in color and save as other viewing format. I have tried the following piece of code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = plt.imread('latest_0013679_caz.tiff')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

But it generate gray scale image as shown below.

[image]

Is there a way around to display tiff file in color?

Comment: Can you post how your tiff looks like? Is it a grey scale image?

Comment: If it is a color image, `imshow()` show display it in color.  Are you sure the image actually has colors?  Run `print(img.shape)`

Comment: It is not a gray scale image as viewed on the default experimental software. However, when I tried to display it using the above code it shows as gray scale as the picture above

Comment: When I run the print (img.shape) command, the ouput is: 
(619L, 487L, 4L)

Comment: Are the first three values in, say, `img[300, 200, :]` all different?

Comment: something like this: img
Out[21]: 
array([[[  7,   7,   7, 255],
        [  5,   5,   5, 255],
        [  7,   7,   7, 255],
        ..., 
        [  6,   6,   6, 255],
        [  9,   9,   9, 255],
        [  8,   8,   8, 255]],
       ..., 
       [[  2,   2,   2, 255],
        [  6,   6,   6, 255],
        [  8,   8,   8, 255],
        ..., 
        ..., 
        ..., 
        [  6,   6,   6, 255],
        [  6,   6,   6, 255],
        [  4,   4,   4, 255]]], dtype=uint8)

Comment: Those are all shades of gray; they are RGBA  (red, green, blue, alpha) values, but in each case, R=G=B, which means the color is gray.

Comment: If your "experimental software" adds color by showing large values with, say, red and small values with, say, blue, you could do something similar with `imshow(img[:,:,0], cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm)`.  You can change the color scheme by changing the `cmap` argument (e.g. `cmap=plt.cm.Spectral` or `cmap=plt.cm.hot`).

Comment: Thanks. It seems now look as it viewed on the software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the image is a grayscale image stored as an RGBA tiff file.  To display the image with a colormap, you can do:

```
img = plt.imread('latest_0013679_caz.tiff')
plt.imshow(img[:, :, 0], cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm)
```

You can change the color scheme by changing the `cmap` argument (e.g. `cmap=plt.cm.Spectral` or `cmap=plt.cm.hot`).