# Importing a .tif into Jupyter Notebook using python script

Tags: python, jupyter, tiff

I have been trying to import a .tif into python using the following code:

```
image = 'location/map_Western_Cape.tif' #use same location as above
geemap.plot_raster(image, cmap='terrain', figsize=(15, 10))

image_Gauteng = 'location/map_Gauteng.tif' #use same location as above
geemap.plot_raster(image, cmap='terrain', figsize=(15, 10))
```

However, I keep getting this error message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [11], in <cell line: 4>()
      1 # Load the .tif from local machine
      3 image = 'C:/Users/kiral/OneDrive - Stellenbosch University/BScHons Global Change/Guy/map_Western_Cape.tif' #use same location as above
----> 4 geemap.plot_raster(image, cmap='terrain', figsize=(15, 10))
      6 image_Gauteng = 'C:/Users/kiral/OneDrive - Stellenbosch University/BScHons Global Change/Guy/map_Gauteng.tif' #use same location as above
      7 geemap.plot_raster(image, cmap='terrain', figsize=(15, 10))

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geemap\common.py:12559, in plot_raster(image, band, cmap, proj, figsize, open_kwargs, **kwargs)
  12557 try:
  12558     import pvxarray
> 12559     import rioxarray
  12560     import xarray
  12561 except ImportError:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rioxarray\__init__.py:6, in <module>
      3 __author__ = """rioxarray Contributors"""
      4 __email__ = "alansnow21@gmail.com"
----> 6 import rioxarray.raster_array  # noqa
      7 import rioxarray.raster_dataset  # noqa
      8 from rioxarray._io import open_rasterio  # noqa

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rioxarray\raster_array.py:28, in <module>
     14 from typing import (
     15     Any,
     16     Dict,
   (...)
     24     Union,
     25 )
     27 import numpy as np
---> 28 import rasterio
     29 import rasterio.mask
     30 import rasterio.warp

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rasterio\__init__.py:44, in <module>
     41 import warnings
     43 import rasterio._loading
---> 44 with rasterio._loading.add_gdal_dll_directories():
     45     from rasterio._show_versions import show_versions
     46     from rasterio._version import gdal_version, get_geos_version, get_proj_version

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'rasterio' has no attribute '_loading' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I have tried installing all of the listed modules, but that ended up getting a bunch of errors too.

Could anyone recommend a way to import these tifs?

Comment: Your title should be more specific as you are trying to work with `geemap` to view your tif file in Jupyter. Going [here](https://geemap.org/notebooks/119_plot_raster/) and pressing `launch binder` and then trying to run the first few cells [there](https://geemap.org/notebooks/119_plot_raster/)  to show the retrieved tif file fail saying to install addition dependencies via pip. Installing those still fails as it seems GL hardware related software isn't installed correctly. And so it's no surprisingly you are having issues as one of their offered ways to run it doesn't even work presently. ...

Comment: <continued>... I can see the tif file in the notebook using the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34165941/8508004).

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/giswqs/geemap/issues/125#issuecomment-667300915) seems to say you want to use conda if you can because installations difficult. (This still doesn't really explain why the version served by MyBinder doesn't work.)